# Comparar 2 Arquivos de Texto, e encontrar palavras iguais

Tags: algoritmo-de-busca, txt

existe alguma ferramenta que localize palavras iguais em 2 arquivos de texto diferente?

**exemplo:**

arquivo1.txt

```
pedra
cavalo
torre
animal
fogo
```

arquivo2.txt

```
garoto
animal
festa
humano
fogo
```

resultado:

```
animal
fogo
```

não é necessário ser 2 arquivos .txt exatamente, mas apenas 2 textos diferente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você não especificou a linguagem, vou oferecer a solução mais simples, em bash.

```
$ grep -f arquivo1.txt arquivo2.txt
> animal
> fogo
```

O parâmetro -f diz pro grep pegar o que será buscado do arquivo. Assim ele vai buscar todas as palavras do `arquivo1.txt` no `arquivo2.txt`

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, consegui o que eu queria, não é linguagem de programação nenhuma, são apenas textos simples, mas agora tenho outra dúvida, existe alguma forma de remover uma lista de palavras de um texto?

> lista_de_palavras:
garoto
humano

> texto:
garoto
animal
festa
humano
fogo

> resultado:
animal
festa
fogo